# Realizar um Sum geral com todos os campos

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho as seguintes tabelas: tb_produto, tb_movimento

```
COD_PROD  | DESCRICAO | TIPO     | 
|01       | CEBOLA    | ALIMENTO |
|02       | ARROZ     | ALIMENTO |
|03       | CARNE     | ALIMENTO |
|04       | COCA-COLA | BEBIDA   |
|05       | PINGA     | BEBIDA   |

COD_MOV | COD_PROD | QUANT.| 
|01     |  01      | 5     |
|02     |  05      | 8     |
|03     |  02      | 10    |
|04     |  05      | 4     |
|05     |  03      | 1     |
```

sql

```
 select 
  CASE WHEN tb_produto.tipo = 'ALIMENTO' THEN
    sum(tb_movimento.QUANT*1)
  ELSE
    SUM(tb_movimento.QUANT*2)
  END
 from tb_movimento, tb_produto
 where (tb_produto.cod_prod = tb_movimento.cod_prod)
 group by tb_produto.tipo
```

Meu retorno:

```
|CASE|
|16  |
|24  |
```

No meu caso gostaria que me retorna-se:

```
|CASE|
|40  |
```

Comment: Não é só tirar o group by?

Comment: Seu eu tirar o groyp by ele não roda "Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tem dois tipos de produtos e o select esta agrupando por tipos de 
produto é natural que ele exiba o resultado desse modo.

> Não tenho o FIREBIRD para testar e estou postando uma resposta testada
>   no Oracle, pelo o que me lembro, funciona no seu banco sem problemas.
>
> Se tiver problemas no seu banco poste aqui que corrigimos.

Faça assim:

```
select sum( total ) from (  
 select 
  CASE WHEN tb_produto.tipo = 'ALIMENTO' THEN
    sum(tb_movimento.QUANT*1)
  ELSE
    SUM(tb_movimento.QUANT*2)
  END as total
 from tb_movimento, tb_produto
 where (tb_produto.cod_prod = tb_movimento.cod_prod)
 group by tb_produto.tipo ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

`select 
sum(tb_movimento.QUANT * (case when tb_produto.tipo='ALIMENTO' then 1 else 2 end)) 
from tb_movimento 
inner join tb_produto on tb_produto.cod_prod = tb_movimento.cod_prod`

Melhoria:
Case usado para definir o fator  de multiplicação.